# SVG animation problem - circle animation off center

Tags: animation, svg

Can someone, please, check this codepen and figure out why the SUN animation is out of place, off the center?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/mbenmos/pen/ywYebE)

```
  <svg version="1.1"
   id="sun"
   class="climacon climacon_sun"
   viewBox="15 15 70 70">
<clipPath id="sunFillClip">
  <path d="M0,0v100h100V0H0z M50.001,57.999c-4.417,0-8-3.582-8-7.999c0-4.418,3.582-7.999,8-7.999s7.998,3.581,7.998,7.999C57.999,54.417,54.418,57.999,50.001,57.999z"/>
</clipPath>
```

Comment: It is always better to keep excerpt code.. Anyway, you should apply the rotate and scale animation to whole svg but not each element inside it. Try adding the animation to the sun's svg element.

Comment: Add transform-box: fill-box; to your g, path, circle, rect {

Comment: @enxaneta -- Thanks, that worked perfectly. can you put that as an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, putting `transform-box: fill-box` in your CSS class that will do the trick. If you need wider browser support - just use separate CSS class for special browsers, like Edge, with pixel-perfect transform-origin property and toggle between classes with JS.

```
.modern{
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
.edge{
  transform-origin: 52px 34px;
}
```

[Your working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxbaoL)

[Also, please refer to other popular solutions for major use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54942444/1828508)